# How can an author write a piece of upmarket fiction effectively?

Tags: publishing

I just wanted to ask a question on behalf of an aspiring author friend. How can an author write a piece of upmarket fiction effectively? She used to lean towards writing strictly literary fiction, but as of recent - and perhaps with the recent unpublished news for certain types of insiders within the U.S. and Canada, it seems major publishers seem to be downscaling the market for this type of fiction. I gave her an example of a piece of upmarket fiction for which I have personally written in my youth - despite me being in my early thirties now, and this is a major stageplay produced by Theatre Jacksonville back-in-the-day prior to 2012. I just wanted some insight - a second opinion, for this friend of mine.

She is a motivated aspiring novelist working a traditional day-job.

I'm just an actor and playwright prior to 1 May 2017.

Is there a balancing act between writing upmarket fiction for any entertainment medium - publishing, stage or screen? Especially since this author tends to lean with her newfound spirituality by tuning into Steven Furtick's Elevation Church Sermons on YouTube and Joel Osteen Ministries.

In my personal opinion, this is a possibility to balance this. I would say to her privately if given an opportunity through her former boyfriend - she's outside my network, that to do this: she can introduce in some way a soft-progressive view on race/culture alone, if present in her fiction, and to stay away from far-right political conservativism that stretches from the 1980s under Ronald Reagan, which is the reason why people don't talk about religion in general. She can go for the themes, the thematic material, which is what makes literary fiction shine and the sentence structure - the use of language, compared to the strictly commercial fiction, like James Patterson and his contemporaries.

Comment: Can you streamline your question a little? I believe there is a lot information which has no bearing at all on what you're asking, and it only distracts.

Comment: I concur with @Joachim, and I think there isn't a specific question here.  Stripping away what I think has no bearing, the underlying question is very broad and unspecific.